# Thymeleaf partial ajax render

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I made a project in spring and thymeleaf. I want to do **ajax rendering** at every page means i don't want that page loads at every request. how can i achieve this please provide me any demo application in which page doesn't load at every request.

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question corretly, what you are looking for is fragment rendering. Maybe this [post](http://forum.thymeleaf.org/Partial-AJAX-Rendering-td4025415.html) will help (look at the answers).